# Odd OpenCV linkage error, using Visual Studio Compiler

Tags: c++, opencv

I encounter the following linkage error when running a simple OpenCV project:

```
LNK1104: cannot open file 'win32:LIBS.obj'
```

I find the error quite odd since it appears on some computers, while on others OpenCV works just fine, even if the computers have the same setup. LIBS.obj does not seem to exist on any of the computers I have tested (Google doesn't help me much as the path to the lib folder etc. seems to be correct...)

Code, using QtCreator with Visual Studio Compiler and OpenCV 2.4 (other versions also tested):

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/highgui.hpp"
int main() {
   cv::namedWindow("hello", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
   cv::waitKey();
}
```

Added lines to QtCreator project file:

```
win32:INCLUDEPATH += C:\opencv\build\include
win32:LIBS += -L"C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin" \
win32:LIBS += -L"C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin" \
              -L"C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib" \
win32:LIBS += -lopencv_core2410d -lopencv_highgui2410d
```

The project has been qmaked/cleaned/rebuild etc. The computer setup can vary (e.g. I've had the same problem on Windows 7/8/8.1.). A particular setup where the program works fine on one computer, while on another computer it doesn't:

- Windows 8.1
- QtCreator (Qt version 5.4)
- Visual Studio Compiler (x86_amd64)
- OpenCV 2.4.10, pre-build, extracted to C:/opencv folder

Any suggestion to how I might go about debugging this linkage error (and yes, I've done the obvious things like checking paths, 32 vs. 64 bit compatibility etc.)?

Comment: looks like you have added the value win32:LIBS to your linking command instead of the value of the variable win32:LIBS? not sure but maybe the ` : ` is a problem within the variable name?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, only the static libs(.lib) directory is added to `win32:LIBS`. The dynamic libraries are specified in the environment variable `PATH`. 
Try removing the line:

`win32:LIBS += -L"C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin"`

and add this directory to your project `PATH` instead by clicking the project properties tab in QtCreator.
`